# Select records where date == now + 21 days (NOT between)

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, intervals, unix-timestamp

I have a table `session_dates` with some fields and a **timestamp** field named `timestart`.

What I would like to do is select all the records from my table where the field **timestart** (TIMESTAMP) is **equal to 21 days from now**.

Like for example **if today is 27 januari -> 17 februari**.

I know how I can select all between two dates.
My SQL Query for between 2 dates:

```
SELECT timestart, timefinish, sessionid 
FROM sessions_dates 
WHERE timestart BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))
```

But how to select equal  to a date?

**UPDATE:**

I know now that I just have to use the = statement. But how can I test this? How do I know what the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))` returns?

Comment: `WHERE timestart = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY))`?

Comment: Use `=` instead of `between`?

Comment: try something ?.. You could try for example using `=` to compare values that are `=` .. maybe that would work..

Comment: Thanks for your reactions, and how can I know what day "DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)" gives back?

Comment: Updated my topic with the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT timestart, timefinish, sessionid 
FROM sessions_dates 
WHERE timestart >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)) AND
      tmestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 22 DAY))
```

Presumably, `timestart` has a time component.  This version takes that into account and still would allow the use of an index on `timestart`.